# WinJS custom control: winControl undefined

Tags: javascript, windows, winjs

I have created a custom WinJS control.

```
<div id="hub" class="fullScreen" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Hub">
  <div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.HubSection">
    <div id="weather-today" data-win-control="RTBF.UI.WeatherView">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I enter the 'ready' method of the same PageControl, the winControl property is undefined. The 'hub' at the other hand has a functioning winControl property. I also see that the contstructor of my control is called, after the ready method. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the winControl property is not done automatically by virtue of using data-win-control. The HTML attribute simply tells WinJS.UI.process[All] the name of the constructor, and it's up to the constructor to do everything else.

The pattern that all WinJS controls follow, which you can see in it's ui.js file, is as follows, assuming *element* is the root div:

```
element.winControl = this;
this.element = element;
```

It's also recommended that you make the control "disposable" by implementing a dispose method, setting this._disposed = false, and adding the "win-disposable" CSS class. (Or use WinJS.UI.markDisposable.)

For all the details, refer to Chapter 5 of my free ebook, Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition (http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2), in the last section named "Custom Controls."